# If Statement to Change Image source using Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is change the source of an image within some bootstrap tabs I placed in my HTML with the click of a button. Not sure where I am going wrong with this. When I run the code nothing will happen. No console errors are present either. The script is referenced externally at the top of my HTML. I would prefer to stay within the Javascript realm for the sake of learning.

### HTML

```
<div id="vehicleModelFrame">
        <button id="modelFrameButton1" type="button" onclick="showTrim1()"></button>
        <button id="modelFrameButton2" type="button" onclick="showTrim2()"></button>
        <button id="modelFrameButton3" type="button" onclick="showTrim3()"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="selectTrimTitle">
        <h3>
            Vehicle Trim
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="vehicleTrimFrame">
        <div class="trimSelector">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Trim 1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Trim 2</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Trim 3</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Trim 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
                    <img id="carLogo1" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo2" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo3" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo4" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function showTrim1() {

var imgback = document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1");
var imgsrc = document.getElementById("carLogo1");

    if (imgback.style.backgroundImage == "url('JeepWrangler.png')") {
        imgsrc.src = "jeep_wrangler.png";

    }

}
```

Comment: It's likely because your IF statement is not true.  So, the changing of the SRC is not firing.  Are you positive that the condition you are looking for is TRUE?  That is, you should probably add an ALERT(imgback.style.backgroundImage) to see what that thing actually IS.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Yes, I should have elaborated more, but I have a series of buttons to click that determine the background image of the "modelFrameButton". The background image in the button displays just fine.

Comment: add a breakpoint to your code so you can inspect what is going on: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink The first line of the if statement seems to work but the second line isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what will have to happen for your goal to be accomplished:

1. Your function has to be called when the button is clicked.
2. The function that is called has to find the `img` DOM element you're interested in.
3. The function has to change the `src` property of that `img`.

Here is how you'd do this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var newSrc = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1';
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    img.src = newSrc;
  });
});
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200 '>
<button>Change src</button>
```

As for what is going wrong in your code, it's hard to say. Does `showTrim()` get called? Do your `document.getElementById`s work? Does your `if` statement get hit? Etc.

Notes:

- Try to adhere to [these guidelines](http://sscce.org/) when asking questions.
- It's really important to indent and format your code properly. It makes it much easier to understand and debug.
- `onclick` is considered to be bad practice. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is the way to go.

Comment: I set break points in the code for this. The onclick="showTrim1()" is called. Inspecting the Javascript, it is trying to run the if statement. It's almost as if it's not finding the background image of the the modelFrameButton.

Comment: What does `imgsrc` log out? Try using `http://lorempixel.com/400/200` instead of `jeep_wrangler.png`. Maybe the `jeep_wrangler.png` path is the problem.

Comment: Would it be because the images are stored locally on my laptop? Do I need an absolute path to the image at that point?

Comment: You don't need an absolute path, you can use a relative path. As for what your relative path will be, that will depend on where your image is relative to the folder you're in. Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) out, and if you're still having trouble, post what your file structure is and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my issue was with this. The comparison operator I was using in my if statement was incorrect. Instead of using `=` I was using `==` which is apparently incorrect in my case. New code works just fine.

### JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").addEventListener("click", function showTrim1(){
var carImg = document.getElementById("carLogo1");

if (document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage = "JeepWrangler.png") {
    carImg.src = "Jeep_Wrangler.png";
}else{
    alert(document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage);

}
```

});

I did end up replacing my "onclicks" with event listeners as well. Thank you all for your help!